# VS for MAC and DocumentDb.Core - BCrypt.DLL missing

Tags: visual-studio, azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

When I get to the line `new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://192.168.30.104:10251"), _key)` I get a `bcrypt.dll not found`.
I'm using VS for Mac, latests version and DocumentDb.Core nugget package version 1.3.2 (latest version)...

I took a shot and downgrade to version 1.0.0 but i got the same error...

the stack trace is:

> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SecureStringHMACSHA256Helper.NativeMethods.BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(IntPtr& algorithmHandle, String algorithmId, IntPtr implementation, UInt32 flags)
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SecureStringHMACSHA256Helper..ctor(SecureString base64EncodedKey)
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri serviceEndpoint, SecureString authKey, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel)

**Edit1**
I mailed the code to a friend, and he ran it on regular VS 2017 and there was no error

Comment: A simple Google search suggests that if you use the constructor for `DocumentClient` that doesn't use a `SecureString` then it might work...

Comment: @DavidG precisely... and i JUST figured that out... came here to answer this myself and read your comment... go ahead and post it as answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than one constructor for the `DocumentClient` class. You are using the [one that takes a `SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.documentclient.aspx#Anchor_9) as the second parameter. If instead you use the [constructor that takes a plain `string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.documentclient.aspx#Anchor_12) then your code should work.

I do agree that this is likely a bug though.